# Error al validar formulario Laravel 8

Tags: formularios, validación, laravel-8

Estoy aprendiendo el uso de laravel mediante videos y leyendo la documentación, pero al momento de hacer la validación de un formulario tengo un problema y es que si ingreso un dato no válido a proposito, en lugar de regresarme el error, solo me manda la pantalla de error con lo siguiente:

[image: Error]

Ahora bien, el formulario se encuentra en una vista y posee su debido csrf.

```
    <form action="/crearRegistro" method="POST">
    <p>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <span class="nav-link active colorTarjeta bg-light" aria-current="page"><strong>DATOS PERSONALES</strong></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="Nombres"><span class="text-danger"><strong>*</span> Nombre(s)</strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nombres" value="{{ old('Nombres') }}" placeholder="Nombre(s)" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="Apellido_Paterno"><span class="text-danger"><strong>*</span> Apellido Paterno</strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Apellido_Paterno" value="{{ old('Apellido_Paterno') }}" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="Apellido_Materno"><span class="text-danger"><strong>*</span> Apellido Materno</strong></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Apellido_Materno" value="{{ old('Apellido_Materno') }}" placeholder="Apellido Materno" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="aceptoTerminos" name="aceptoTerminos" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="aceptoTerminos">
                    <span class="text-danger"><strong>*</strong></span> Acepto que Servicios a la Navegación en el Espacio Aéreo Mexicano, “SENEAM”, será responsable del tratamiento de datos personales conforme a lo establecido en la Ley Federal de Protección de Datos Personales en Posesión de Sujetos Obligados.
                    <p><a href="https://www.seneam.gob.mx/gobmx/transparencia/aviso-de -privacidad-integral.html" target="_blank">Nuestro aviso de privacidad está disponible aquí.</a></p>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="continuar" name="continuar">
            Guardar Datos
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

mi ruta es meramente post y apunta al controlador y métodos apropiados:

```
Route::post('/crearRegistro', [RegistroController::class, 'createRegister']); //Recibo datos participante y registro
```

Y finalmente el codigo del método al que hace referencia es el siguiente:

```
public function createRegister(Request $request){
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'Nombres' => ['required', 'alpha', 'max:15'],
        'Apellido_Paterno' => ['required', 'alpha', 'max:15'],
        'Apellido_Materno' => ['required', 'alpha', 'max:15'],
        'aceptoTerminos' => ['required', 'boolean']
    ]);

    return request();
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar la falla. Como nota es la ultima versión de laravel disponible mediante composer.

Comment: Si estaba el @csrf :) El error estaba en el tipo de ruta, ya que no comprendía el error que regresaba.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de un buen clavado en la documentación de rutas, me di cuenta que el problema es que solo estaba puesto como post y por lo tanto no recuperaba datos con get, por lo que la solución fue cambiar mi ruta de:

```
Route::post('/registro', [RegistroController::class, 'createForm'])->name('registro'); //Al controlador registro
```

por...

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/registro', [RegistroController::class, 'createForm'])->name('registro'); //Al controlador registro
```